# Android custom header and tabs below

Tags: android, android-xml

I am new to android so i need help. I want to know how to add header (which i made in xml by my own) and tabs below it. So when my app start above header and below my header tabs will show.

Need guidance i will appreciate that.

```
header.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dip"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:background="#010000"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Logo -->

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

<!-- Plus Button -->

<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/plus"
    android:id="@+id/btnAddSite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need tabs below

```
  package com.lab.rssnewsreader;

   import android.app.TabActivity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.res.Resources;
   import android.graphics.Color;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.TabHost;
   import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Resources res= getResources();
            TabHost tabhost =getTabHost();
            TabSpec pakistanspec= tabhost.newTabSpec("pakistan");
            pakistanspec.setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.pakistan) );
            Intent intent =new Intent(this, Pakistan_News.class);
            pakistanspec.setContent(intent);

            TabSpec worldspec= tabhost.newTabSpec("world");
            worldspec.setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.world) );
            Intent intent2 =new Intent(this, World_News.class);
            worldspec.setContent(intent2);

            TabSpec favspec= tabhost.newTabSpec("favourite");
            favspec.setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.fav) );
            Intent intent3 =new Intent(this, Favourite_News.class);
            favspec.setContent(intent3);

            tabhost.addTab(pakistanspec);
            tabhost.addTab(worldspec);
            tabhost.addTab(favspec);

            tabhost.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tabhost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

}
```

Comment: do you have something you seen already so we can guide you by providing us a screenshot of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I want you to give me the way how can i do. I don't have screenshot just imagine to do in may project work.

Comment: so you just want to add tabs below the toolBar or ActionBar right?

Comment: I edit my code please see that.